# Remove a specific item from a Set in Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a Set of Strings in my sharedPrefs. I would like to remove a specific item in the list

```
<set name="items">
<string>217372223</string>
<string>222015066</string>
<string>217771052</string>
<string>220431322</string>
```

So I would like to just remove say, 217372223 but keep the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `remove(String key)` method of [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("items", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().remove(String key).commit();
```

Make sure your entry has a key. Try something like this:

```
<string name="keyToDelete">217372223</string>
```

and then

```
sharedPreferences.edit().remove("keyToDelete").commit();
```

Comment: and if i use

preferences.edit().remove("items").commit();

Would this remove the whole list?

Comment: @x10sion In that case it would be better to use `clear()`, which removes **all** preferences.

Comment: Why do you use "String key" in the above example?

Comment: @x10sion it's to say that you should replace it with the key of the entry you want to delete, and that this key is a string

Comment: Ive just tested your solution and maybe its my mistake in the question but the code i have given you is not all the data in the SharedPrefs file, this is just the portion i wish to work with. I tried using your way of removing the items and it didnt work, it only worked when i used the "items" as the key, but this removed the whole Set. When i tried using one of the ID's it did not remove the single item in the Set

Comment: @x10sion That's probably because your other entries are missing the keys, i.e. they only contain values. Try adding `name="testkey"` to one of your entries (similar to what happens with your `items` menu) and see if that works.

Comment: @x10sion I have updated the answer, see if you can make it work now. It's worth trying as it would be more efficient than your solution of deleting everything and reinserting everything.

Comment: I have tried that and it works fine, the problem i have is a List of strings in a Set saved in the SharedPrefs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html <--see here and i needed to delete a specific item in the list. the way you suggested only deleted items with a key, but my values i wanted to delete were in a set and the specific item i wanted didnt have its own Key so there was no way to reference it specifically

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
   * Deletes a particular value or FULL Set from shared preferences.
   *
   * @param key
   */
  public static void deleteValueInPreferences(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sp.contains(key)) {
      sp.edit().remove(key).apply();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Deletes a particular value in Set from shared preferences.
   *
   * @param key
   */
  public static void deleteSingleValueInSetInPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    Set<String> aSetOfExistingStrings = getStringArrayFromPreferences(context, key);
    deleteValueInPreferences(context, key);
    Set<String> aNewSetOfExistingStrings = new HashSet<String>();
    aNewSetOfExistingStrings.addAll(aSetOfExistingStrings);
    aNewSetOfExistingStrings.remove(value);
    setStringArrayIntoPreferences(context, key, aNewSetOfExistingStrings);
  }
  /**
   * @param context
   * @param key - Set Key
   * @param keyValueMap - Set Key List
   */
  public static void setStringArrayIntoPreferences(Context context, String key, Set<String> keyValueMap) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (String s : keyValueMap) {
    }
    sp.edit().putStringSet(key, keyValueMap).apply();
  }
```

This is how I over came the issue I was having. I copied the Set from SharedPrefs, removed the item I wanted to remove, removed the whole set from SharedPrefs, then re-added the set minus the item I wanted removed.